# Returning a specific type of entry in a table (SQL)

Tags: mysql

I have three tables Buildings, EnergyType and EnergyCategory. The first two are connected by a bridge table called build_types. The second two are connected by having related IDs (type_ID = cat_ID).

This join outputs buildings and every energy type they use:

```
SELECT B.building, E.energytype
FROM Buildings b
INNER JOIN build_types bt ON B.build_ID = bt.build_ID
INNER JOIN EnergyTypes e ON bt.type_ID = E.type_ID
ORDER BY B.building;
```

This join outputs the total number count of each energy type:

```
SELECT E.energytype, COUNT(*)
FROM Buildings b
LEFT JOIN build_types bt ON B.build_ID = bt.build_ID
LEFT JOIN EnergyTypes e ON bt.type_ID = E.type_ID
GROUP BY E.energytype;
```

I want a select statement that will return a table with building name on the left and energy category on the right, with only categories described that are 'Renewable'. I have:

```
SELECT B.building, E.energytype, E.energycategory
FROM Buildings b
INNER JOIN build_types bt ON B.build_ID = bt.build_ID
INNER JOIN EnergyTypes e ON bt.type_ID = E.type_ID
INNER JOIN EnergyCategories e ON E.cat_ID = E.type_ID
WHERE E.energycategory = 'Renewable';
```

but I get Error 1066: Not unique table/alias 'EnergyTypes'.

Comment: I think the error is because you have two of the table alias as e. Change one of them

Comment: type_ID = cat_ID - this sounds like an accident waiting to happen

Comment: Make the alias for energy categories to like ec

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen the alias "E" for both `EnergyTypes` and `EnergyCategories`.

```
SELECT B.building, T.energytype, C.energycategory
FROM Buildings b
INNER JOIN build_types bt ON B.build_ID = bt.build_ID
INNER JOIN EnergyTypes T ON bt.type_ID = T.type_ID
INNER JOIN EnergyCategories C ON C.cat_ID = T.type_ID
WHERE C.energycategory = 'Renewable';
```

should work.

Comment: Why is the alias important? Could I have written 
SELECT Buildings.building, EnergyTypes.energytype, EnergyCategories.energycategory?

Answer (score 0):

Change the alias for one of the tables.  Make 'e' something else for one of them.